# ProviderContainer and GoRouter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-go-router, flutter-local-notification

I want to read the GoRouter outside of `main()` and outside of any widget.

GoRouter provider is defined as follows:

```
final goRouterProvider = Provider<GoRouter>(
  (ref) {
    return GoRouter(...);
}
```

Then when I'm initializing `flutter_local_notifications` I want to read this provider using ProviderContainer, similar to how I'm doing on `main()` method:

```
static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _localNotificationsPlugin =FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

_localNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
  initializationSettings,
  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) async {
      final container = ProviderContainer();
      container.read(goRouterProvider).pushNamed(AppRoute.someRandomRoute.name);
  },
);
```

In this case I still end up in the same screen (no navigation action is taken) but with the same logs as when GoRouter initialises (due to `debugLogDiagnostics: true` flag).

I compared this to passing down the container from the `main()` method which does navigate to the destination as expected.

Does this mean that ProviderContainer().read(goRouterProvider) is creating a new GoRouter instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's right, it's a new copy. To get the old instance, you need the very container in which it will lie.

You can either cast a container with an argument or get it through a `BuildContext`:

```dart
final providerContainer = ProviderScope.containerOf(context);
```

But one way or another, you need access to the container to get the value of the old instances.

Answer (score 1):

The description of [`ProviderContainer`](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/ProviderContainer-class.html) indicates that it is *"an object that stores the state of the providers and allows overriding the behavior of a specific provider"*. Which means that the states of your providers are scoped to that container.

When you are using Riverpod in a Flutter app, the container is implicitly created for you by `ProviderScope`, which means that **if you create another container somewhere else it will not be the same as the one used internally by you Flutter app**... and consequently they will NOT share the same states.

You could just declare your router as a global variable, for example in a <router.dart> file have:

```dart
/// Navigation router.
final GoRouter kRouter = new GoRouter(
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd rather keep it this way as it makes more sense and not have a separate key for navigation :).

Comment: You dont need to provide a separate key for navigation. I would advice against having your router as part of the states of your providers. The router is a core object of you app.

Comment: with the architecutre I'm currently using, providing the router works pretty well and I'm really happy with it. I can use it inside `ConsumerStatefulWidget`s all lifecycles and navigate to a separate screen. I think the same could be achieved with your approach as well.